# Can I count on the "python3" executable being available on Python 3 installations? Or "python"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a Python command that I want to share with people widely. Let's take it as a given that Python 3 is installed. Which binary should I expect users to have, `python` or `python3`?

For example, which is better, to tell users to run this:

```
python -m http.server
```

or to run this

```
python3 -m http.server
```

?

In Ubuntu 22.10, the `python3` binary is available, but not `python`, so the latter would be better. Can I expect the same for all Python 3 installations on different operating systems?

Please note that I am not trying to support Python 2 at all, [as it has been sunset](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/), and Python 3 has been available since 2006.

Comment: There's never been any guarantee about the name or location of a Python executable. ChaosOS could install it as `/etc/definitely-not-python` if it were so inclined. This isn't something Python specifies, and it's not a problem for you, the person distributing a script written in Python, need concern yourself about.

Comment: Package your code properly, and it's entirely up to the *installer* which Python to use to execute the code (within the version requirements specified by your package).

Comment: Installers will patch any shebang containing the word `python` to refer to version of Python used during installation. (And most packaging tools don't require you to provide an executable script at all; they can be generated automatically at install time given an entry point into a *module*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your operating system.

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#python-related-paths-and-files), the interpreter will be located at `/usr/bin/python3` on Unix systems.

Although many linux versions or install scripts will include a symlink at `/usr/bin/python` pointing to the interpreter, I wouldn't *count* on it.

On Windows however, the interpreter will be called with `python`. `python3.x` being used to [install the corresponding version from the Windows Store](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#the-microsoft-store-package)

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3` is a recommendation, not a requirement, and assumes an `exec_prefix` of `/usr` (which won't be true for a virtual environment).

Comment: @chepner you are right, it isn't necessarily installed under `/usr` (see the link I shared). However I think it is a *reasonable assumption* to count on python to be found in path as `python3` on Unix systems.

Comment: You don't need to make any reasonable assumptions, though. It's not the job of the script's author to provide any indication of *where* the appropriate Python implementation *should* be to execute the script.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question but to me it looks like OP is trying to explain/show other users the command they have to run (like in a documentation/tutorial). I wasn't thinking about a script or an installer...

Comment: That's still not something the author should concern themselves with. I think knowing how to run Python on their machine is an acceptable minimal level of competence to assume. If you can't assume that, build an executable using something like `pyinstaller`.